# Implicit newline at the end of each paragraph?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

In certain styles of text I define `\parindent 0pt` in the preamble and write the text in this manner:

```
paragraph 1\\

paragraph 2\\
```

and so forth. I wonder if there is anything I can include in the preamble for instance to modify how the end of paragraphs are interpreted so I don't have to include the `\\` at the end of each?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
```

or perhaps better use

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

and *never* end a paragraph with `\\` it just makes LaTeX generate loads of warnings and poor typesetting.

Comment: You can as well use `{\baselineskip plus 0.15\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}` to allow some stretch.

Comment: Yes that's better really (or there's the `parskip` package for a more complete job) I was was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: The `parskip` package is exactly what I needed - but the simplicity of this answer is nice too. When I try to compile with @tohecz answer though I get `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`.

Comment: @tohecz comment was intended to be the argument to `\setlength` not a line on its own.