# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) message

Tags: pdftex, minipage

I made a mini page like below. It compiled without any error, however, I am getting following message in log:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 104--109
```

I am trying to fix above message.

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \dotfill\\
    Prof. XYZ\\
    Department of XYZ\\
    University of whatever, \\
    City, Country\\

    Date: ............\\
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Remove `\\` from the last two lines:

```
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \dotfill\\
    Prof. XYZ\\
    Department of XYZ\\
    University of whatever, \\
    City, Country              %<--- here

    Date: ............         %<----and here
\end{minipage}
```

Bad boxes should go away. Forcing a line break followed by a blank line{which amounts to a paragraph break) and a line break after the last line are responsible for the bad boxes.

Comment: there are literally hundreds of messages answering this question.  one that has been cited before is [Implicit newline at the end of each paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66533/579).  it would be a good thing to have a "stock" question that can be cited as a duplicate, that would explain many situations.